# Magento: how to easily recalculate tax on a given total

Tags: php, magento

What I want to do  getting the cart items object and store it in new variable, looping through them, change their price then I want to recalculate the tax on the new total.

how to achieve this in least steps possible.

this is the code I made, but taxes understandably not being recalculated as I haven't been able to do that:

```
            $items=$address ;// add is of type Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address

            foreach ($items->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
                if ($items->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                try{
                    if ($item){
                        $qty        = $item->getTotalQty();
                        $total      = $item->getCalculationPrice()*$qty*2;
                        $baseTotal  = $item->getBaseCalculationPrice()*$qty*2;

                        $item->setRowTotal(Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($total)); 
                        $item->setBaseRowTotal(Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($baseTotal)); 
                        $item->save();
                    }
                }catch (Exception $e){

                }

            }

            $baseTax = ($items->getTaxBeforeDiscount() ? $items->getTaxBeforeDiscount() : ($items->getTaxAmount() ? $items->getTaxAmount() : 0));
            $tax = ($items->getBaseTaxBeforeDiscount() ? $items->getBaseTaxBeforeDiscount() : ($items->getBaseTaxAmount() ? $items->getBaseTaxAmount() : 0));
```

Comment: you can try and call collectTotals() on this object

Comment: thanks, it didn't work unfortunately, probably because I'm doing this inside a function called fetch extending quote_address_total

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the tax/vat rate, using address' tax amount and grand total. After updating address' grand total use the rate to calculate the new tax amount.

Take a look at the following example

```
/* calculate ratio */
$ratio = ($address->getTaxAmount() / $address->getGrandTotal());
$baseRatio = ($address->getBaseTaxAmount() / $address->getBaseGrandTotal());

/* do price changes */
$address->setGrandTotal(...);
$address->setBaseGrandTotal(...);
/* ... */

/* set new tax amount */
$address->setTaxAmount($address->getGrandTotal() * $ratio);
$address->setBaseTaxAmount($address->getBaseGrandTotal() * $baseRatio);

$address->save();
```